# Depend on package built in workspace

Tags: ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a driver `package_a` and I want modify its dependency `package_b` for use in my project. I downloaded the `package_b` source into my catkin workspace, made the modifications, and successfully built the dependency. However `package_a` is unable to reference the new changes. I think is is because CMake found a different version of `package_b` somewhere else which does not have my modifications. How should I modify my CMakeLists.txt to use the locally build `package_b` in the catkin ws? I run `rospack find package_b` and the path is `catkin_ws/src/package_b`.

```
/catkin_ws
 - /src
   - /package_a
     - CMakeLists.txt
     - package.xml
   - /package_b       
     - CMakeLists.txt
     - package.xml
```

The dependencies listed in `package_a/CMakeLists.txt` is

```
find_package(package_b REQUIRED)
            
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
            
catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    CATKIN_DEPENDS
        ...
    DEPENDS package_b
    )

include_directories(
  include
  ${package_b_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
   )
    
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  ${package_b_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

For reference, the `package_b` is [libcreate](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/libcreate) and `package_a` is [create_robot](https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_robot).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381928/depend-on-package-built-in-workspace/) by [bscout2011](https://answers.ros.org/users/76460/bscout2011/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-07-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2021-07-07**:
CMakeLists reads ok. Also 'rospack find  package_b' command is also outputing correct path. Are you installing the resultant library?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-07**:
Is `package_b` a ROS package? If yes, you should probably have it in the `find_package(catkin...)` command as a component, as well as in `CATKIN_DEPENDS` instead of `DEPENDS`. Also, how exactly do you add `package_b` to the `include_Directories` and `target_link_libraries` calls? Please **edit** your question with the relevant lines of your `CMakeLIsts.txt`.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-07**:
After running catkin_make at least once, have you sourced the setup.bash in `catkin_ws/devel` ?

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

You have to do this for catkin_make to "see" the packages in your home directory.

**Comment by [bscout2011](https://answers.ros.org/users/76460/bscout2011/) on 2021-07-07**:
@prince I am not sure if I am creating an install for `package_b`.

@mgruhler `package_b` is a ROS package and I have the `package_b.so` library in my `/opt/ros/melodic/lib` folder. I added the `inlcude_directories` and `target_link_libraries` to the posted question.

@Mike Scheutzow  The build itself is failing, so sourcing the workspace would not solve the issue.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-08**:
@bscout2011 I'm assuming you followed the build instructions in `libcreate`s Readme and used `catkin_tools` to build it? With a plain `catkin_make` the lib shouldn't compile. This is because `libcreate` is actually not a ROS package, but a plain CMake project (even though the `package.xml` exists), but the `CMakeLIsts.txt` does not `find_package(catkin ...)`.

If you used `catkin_tools`, you actually need to source the workspace once again for the package path to be picked up. This is because `catkin_tools` by default builds the packages in isolation (same holds for `catkin_make_isolated`).

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-08**:
@mgruhler you should post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The build instructions in `libcreate`'s Readme define how `catkin_tools` builds the lib. With a plain `catkin_make` the lib shouldn't compile. This is because `libcreate` is actually not a ROS package, but a plain CMake project (even though the `package.xml` exists), but the `CMakeLIsts.txt` does not `find_package(catkin ...)`.

If you used `catkin_tools`, you actually need to source the workspace once again for the package path to be picked up. This is because `catkin_tools` by default builds the packages in isolation (same holds for `catkin_make_isolated`).

---

Originally posted by [bscout](https://answers.ros.org/users/59069/bscout/) with karma: 16 on 2021-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-07-12**:
So did this solve your problem?

**Comment by [bscout2011](https://answers.ros.org/users/76460/bscout2011/) on 2021-07-12**:
My solution just made the libcreate package a catkin package by editing CMakeLists.txt adding find_package(catkin REQUIRED) and catkin_package(). In general, I think your solution is better because it makes libcreate a system wide package, whereas my solution adds more dependencies to libcreate which may break other systems which do not use catkin.